# This code is not running and giving error for argument type

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int l, b;
    int perimeter, area;
    scanf("%d, %d",l,b);
    area = (l*b);
    perimeter = (2*(l+b));
    printf("%d, %d", area, perimeter);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> main.c:5:13: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *',
>   but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=] scanf("%d, %d",l,b);
>               ~^      ~

What should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717059/how-do-you-use-scanf-to-get-an-int-in-c

Answer (score 3):

The way you read the int variables is wrong. Try:

```
scanf("%d, %d", &l, &b);
```

Nevertheless, you also miss one comma in the print statement. Try:

```
printf("%d, %d",area, perimeter);
```

Comment: "Missing comma" is certainly an error on OP's part (otherwise, it wouldn't have compiled or produced the warnings it did).

Answer (score 2):

This should work. You were using the incorrect syntax with scanf .

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int l, b;
    int perimeter, area;
    scanf("%d %d",&l, &b);
    area = (l*b);
    perimeter = (2*(l+b));
    printf("%d, %d",area, perimeter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int l, b;
    int perimeter, area;
    scanf("%d %d",&l,&b);//when you get user input as int you need to use & operator to get the value
    area = (l*b);
    perimeter = (2*(l+b));
    printf("%d %d",area, perimeter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not an answer.